# commands in bash fail to work with absolute paths

Tags: bash

The following script

```
#!/bin/bash
command="cp -f '/Input Folder/test.txt' '/Output Folder/test.txt'"
echo "["$command"]"
$command
```

gives the following output:

```
[cp -f '/Input Folder/test.txt' '/Output Folder/test.txt']
cp: target ‘Folder/test.txt'’ is not a directory
```

while the command

```
cp -f '/Input Folder/test.txt' '/Output Folder/test.txt'
```

works perfectly fine.

How should i surround paths properly? Does bash imply some kind of special treatment for ' or " symbols?

Comment: ["I'm trying to put a command in a variable, but the complex cases always fail!"](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/050)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use an array instead. Also, `command` is a builtin name. Better use another variable just in case.

```
cmd=(cp -f '/Input Folder/test.txt' '/Output Folder/test.txt')
echo "[${cmd[*]}]"
"${cmd[@]}"
```